# Инфоблоки как у битрикса, но на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли у wordpress похожая система на систему инфоблоков из битрикса, т.е. чтобы в админке можно было создать кастомные новости к примеру, и добавлять эти самые новости в админке, с указанием "Название" и т.п. а после в php обращаться к блоку "Новости" и доставать оттуда параметр "Название". Куда мне стоит копать для этого?

Знаю только то, что в плагинах имеются параметры, но переписывать весь сайт под плагины - такая себе затея))

Comment: Blocki попробуй

Comment: @eri Как я понял это для визуального редактора? У меня сайт полностью уже написан, просто как раз таки нужна система а-ля "инфоблоков" как у битрикса.

Comment: В зависимости от Вашей конечной цели, это может быть Custom Post Type или Custom Fields, если я верно понял Вашу потребность.

Comment: Вам нужно изучить про добавление метаполей к записям, как это работает в WordPress

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Ничего не понятно... Что такое "кастомные новости"? Изучи [типы контента ВП](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/data-types) и обращайся с терминологией правильно. И да, возможно ты про родной [oEmbed](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/oembed)